# Is it possible to get Html source from an URL in Android Studio?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I'm working on a project that requires getting the HTML source code from an URL then displaying it to the screen, is there any way to do that? I tried HttpClient, however, it seems like android studio does not support it anymore.

Comment: `Is it possible to get Html source from an URL in Android Studio?` No. Android Studio will not do that. But you can easy program your Android app to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) - great HTML parser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).